# Where does .NET or Visual Studio store the default form icon?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, icons

You know the default form icon for .NET applications right? The 3 squares each either red, yellow, or blue inside of a square? I need the icon file for it for a project I'm working on and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I have Visual Studio 2010 professional so I have the image library, but that doesn't seem to have the icon (if it does and I missed it you can point that out). I'm just wondering, is the icon in a DLL somewhere or something? If so I wouldn't know where to look, or if it's part of some library or folder. Really I just wanna know where I can find the icon file.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate. I am using VB.NET, not C#.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm using VB.NET not C# so the answers there don't exactly help me.

Comment: I have a better answer: `Me.Icon.Save(...)`